# ¿Como iniciar servicio de SQLEXPRESS 2016 desde aplicacion consola en C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server

tengo el siguiente codigo de un aplicacion en consola en C# para iniciar el servicio de SQLSERVER 2016, pero no he podido, aqui esta el codigo y el error del codigo.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.ServiceProcess;
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
   class Program
   {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string myServiceName = "MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS"; //service name of SQL Server Express
        string status; //service status (For example, Running or Stopped)

        Console.WriteLine("Service: " + myServiceName);

        //display service status: For example, Running, Stopped, or Paused
        ServiceController mySC = new ServiceController(myServiceName);

        try
        {
            status = mySC.Status.ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Service not found. It is probably not installed. [exception=" + ex.Message + "]");
            Console.ReadLine();

            return;

        }

        //display service status: For example, Running, Stopped, or Paused
        Console.WriteLine("Service status : " + status);

        //if service is Stopped or StopPending, you can run it with the following code.
        if (mySC.Status.Equals(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped) | mySC.Status.Equals(ServiceControllerStatus.StopPending))
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Starting the service...");
                mySC.Start();
                mySC.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Running);
                Console.WriteLine("The service is now " + mySC.Status.ToString());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error in starting the service: " + ex.Message);

            }

        }

        Console.WriteLine("Press a key to end the application...");
        Console.ReadLine();

        return;

    }
  }

}
```

y aqui esta el resultado de la aplicacion.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tienen idea de porque no puedo iniciar ese servicio? gracias de antemano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Todo era sobre permisos, tuve que agregar un archivo de manifiesto en mi aplicacion para que la ejecura como Administrador, les dejo unas imagenes para que lo vean.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y tuve que cambiar esta linea

```
<requestedexecutionlevel level="requireAdministrator" uiaccess="false">
</requestedexecutionlevel>
```

ahora la aplicacion no lanza excepcion si el servicio de SQL esta detenido.

Answer (score 0):

Puede ser un error de permisos, ya que para ejecutar el servicio de SQL tu aplicación debe estar corriendo con elevación y como administrador, puedes probarlo ejecutando el comando siguiente desde el símbolo de sistema de Windows:

```
sc start MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS
```

Si el resultado es "*Acceso denegado*", es por permisos, en dado caso compila tu aplicación y prueba ejecutando el EXE como administrador y debe funcionar (clic derecho "Ejecutar como administrador").

También puede ser que el nombre de tu instancia no sea el correcto, en dado caso el primer comando te mandará un resultado como este:

> [SC] StartService: OpenService ERROR 1060:
>
> El servicio especificado no existe como servicio instalado.

Puedes consultar el nombre de tu instancia SQL usando el siguiente comando:

```
sc query | findstr /I MSSQL
```